# Setting up openvpn router on raspberry pi

Tags: routing, raspbian, openvpn

I've got a raspberry pi 3 at home running raspbian, and I would like to setup up an openvpn router, such that I can connect to my provider windscribe by choosing my raspberry pi as the gateway. It is connected by ethernet to my main router, which I do not want to run openvpn on, as it would affect all machines on my network, which would affect gaming. Setting up openvpn or even running it on boot isn't my problem, it's setting up routing that's been affecting me, as iptables-persistent will not install as netfilter-persistent isn't configured yet, and I do not understand how to fix it.